General debugging and help
After running the attached code, I get quite a few errors, as seen in the attached screenshot. I would greatly appreciate any help!
M = 23.58/1000;
l = 0.9;
Ms = (2*2.02)/1000 Sqrt[l^2 - 0.4^2];
NN = 10; 
dl = Sqrt[l^2 - 0.4^2]/NN;
g = 9.81;
e = 0.9229372872377224;
m[n_] := If[n == NN, M, Ms/(NN - 1)];
r[n_, t_] := 
  Sum[UnitVector[3, 1]*dl Sin[\[Theta][i, t]] - 
    UnitVector[3, 3]*dl Cos[\[Theta][i, t]], {i, n}];
rdot[n_, t_] := D[r[n, t], t];
tt[t_] := 1/2 Sum[m[n]*Total[rdot[n, t]^2], {n, NN}];
vv[t_] := g*Sum[m[n]*r[n, t][[3]], {n, NN}];
ll[t_] := tt[t] - vv[t];
rr[t_] := 
  1/2 kvc*Sum[(D[\[Theta][n, t], t] - D[\[Theta][n - 1, t], t])^2, {n,
      2, NN}];
airdamp[t_] := 1/2 cd*Total[rdot[NN, t]^2];
eqLag[k_] := 
  D[D[ll[t], D[\[Theta][k, t], t]], t] - 
    D[ll[t], \[Theta][k, t]] == -D[rr[t], D[\[Theta][k, t], t]];
lastpend := 
  D[D[ll[t], D[\[Theta][NN, t], t]], t] - 
    D[ll[t], \[Theta][NN, t]] == -D[airdamp[t], 
      D[\[Theta][NN, t], t]] - D[rr[t], D[\[Theta][NN, t], t]];

eqs = Join[Table[eqLag[k], {k, NN - 1}], {lastpend} ];
initialData = 
  Flatten[Table[{\[Theta][k, 0] == ArcTan[0.423/-0.723], 
     Derivative[0, 1][\[Theta]][k, 0] == 0}, {k, NN}]];
model[cdd_?NumberQ, kvcc_?NumberQ] := 
 NDSolveValue[Flatten@{eqs, initialData} /. {cd -> cdd, kvc -> kvcc}, 
  Table[\[Theta][k, t], {k, NN}], {t, 0, 75.2}, 
  Method -> {"EquationSimplification" -> "Residual"}, 
  StartingStepSize -> 10^-6, MaxStepFraction -> 1/100000, 
  MaxStepSize -> 10^-6, MaxSteps -> Infinity]

nlm = NonlinearModelFit[dampdata, 
  ArcTan[(dl Sum[Sin[model[cd, kvc][[k]][[0]][t]], {k, NN}])/(
   dl Sum[Cos[model[cd, kvc][[k]][[0]][t]], {k, NN}])], {cd, kvc}, t, 
  Method -> "Gradient"]


edit 1: updated code and screenshot to display new errors.
edit 2: tested the code by substituting dummy values into  ArcTan[(dl Sum[Sin[model[cd, kvc][[k]][[0]][t]], {k, NN}])/(
dl Sum[Cos[model[cd, kvc][[k]][[0]][t]], {k, NN}])] and it works fine, concluded that problem must have something to do with nonlinearmodelfit

Please meet us halfway and produce a minimal example. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example The expectation is that you try to debug issues on your own first, and explain where specifically you got stuck.

Apologies but I'm not too sure where the error is so it's quite challenging to make a minimal example.

Have you read through the page I linked, and have you tried the tips there? Here's another thread with good suggestions: https://mathematica.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2126/12 Start by removing as many pieces of code as possible while still reproducing the error.

apologies I forgot to include the updated code in the post and only added the nonlinearmodelfit. However, i have added your suggestions to my notebook on my computer. Apologies for any misunderstandings

Cross-posted: https://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/3303490

(Extended comment)
When you write Module[{θ, t}, ...], you make θ and t be local variables. This means that they are not the same as θ and t in your equations (which are "global" θ and t). So just remove the Module altogether.
The second issue is again with the scoping, because cd and kvc will not be automatically replaced in your equations. You either have to make them be additional arguments of all your functions, or manually replace them:
model[cdd_?NumberQ, kvcc_?NumberQ] := NDSolveValue[Flatten@{eqs, initialData} /.
  {cd -> cdd, kvc -> kvcc}, ...]

After that, the code runs (but I didn't wait long enough for it to finish).

ah I see thank you, that makes sense. As a follow up question, my next line of code is the NonlinearModelFit equation that I have just edited into the code in the post. After running the code, I get a few errors in the screenshot in the post. Would you mind helping me identify how to solve these issues? (Do let me know if you need dampdata to debug the code) Thank you.

Please first check whether the code runs without NonlinearModelFit. Do you get the result? Only then proceed to NonlinearModelFit. Also, in the edited code, you again included Module, which I suggested you shouldn't :)

apologies I forgot to include the updated code in the post and only added the nonlinearmodelfit. However, i have added your suggestions to my notebook on my computer. Apologies for any misunderstandings.

Yes I have ran the code for the full time duration and it does work without nonlinearmodelfit.
